# PHP, kill Windows process?

Tags: php, windows, kill-process

Is there a way to kill a Windows process, say `calc.exe`, with PHP without using `exec`?

`exec` calls an external program, I try to avoid using that command unless necessary.

Comment: It's ok to use the system calls in PHP if there's no alternative. Just make sure you untaint any user input incorporated into the call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is.

Use the `W32api` PHP extension, which provides access to the Win32 API - then use the `TerminateProcess()` API after aquiring a handle to the process.

Comment: AFAIK the official builds of PHP from windows.php.net have the extension compiled in

Comment: The original question was "Is there a way to kill a **Windows** process"

Answer (score 2):

1. define new function in PHP sources ( pure C )
2. compile you new PHP version with the defined function
3. call the new function, which was defined in PHP sources by you

PS

On this way you are able to make PHP able work with __asm { } insertions/add some kernel code , if you want it...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  PHP has little access to the system except through `exec`.

Comment: True, but I'd be pretty impressed if you made `calc.exe` close using `fopen` ;-)